# Status=403 while login to the website / does not accept credentials using jsoup

Tags: java, web, jsoup

I know there is bunch questions of this type, but i did not find answer for this kind of problem. I'm trying to login to a website but I have two problems. I will post source code below and after that i will explain what is going wrong.

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://xxx.xx.x.xx/website_before_login/index.php")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

//System.out.println(loginForm);

Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://xxx.xx.x.xx/website_after_login/graph_view.php")
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36")
        .data("cookieexists", "false")
        .data("login_username", "login")
        .data("login_password", "password")
        .data("action", "login")
        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
        .post();

System.out.println(document);
```

In this case i get below error:

```
> Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=https://xxx.xx.x.xx/website_after_login/view.php
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:682)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:629)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:261)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.post(HttpConnection.java:256)
    at test.Test_1.main(Test_1.java:89)
```

I want you to know that this website is working only after connecting to VPN so proxy settings are unnecessary here. Additional I turned off certificate validation in Java HTTPS Connections because this was also one of my problem.
Any idea how to resolve whis problem?

I also tried to connect using method get(); instead of post(); - result below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head> 
  <title>Login to Website</title> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"> 
  <style type="text/css">
    <!--
        BODY, TABLE, TR, TD {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-
serif; font-size: 12px;}
        A {text-decoration: none;}
        A:active { text-decoration: none;}
        A:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: #333333;}
        A:visited {color: Blue;}
    -->
    </style> 
  <script type="text/javascript">if (top != self) {top.location.href = 
self.location.href;}</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">var csrfMagicToken = 
"sid:2cab4af55d51696dff403441da56e8f7777b205d,1501588419";var csrfMagicName 
= 
"__csrf_magic";</script>
  <script src="/website/include/csrf/csrf-magic.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
 </head> 
 <body onload="document.login.login_username.focus()"> 
  <form name="login" method="post" action="graph_view.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="__csrf_magic" 
value="sid:2cab4af55d51696dff403441da56e8f7777b205d,1501588419"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login"> 
   <table id="login" align="center"> 
    <tbody>
     <tr> 
      <td colspan="2">
       <center>
        <img src="/website/images/auth_login.gif" border="0" alt="">
       </center></td> 
     </tr> 
     <tr style="height:10px;">
      <td></td>
     </tr> 
     <tr> 
      <td id="error" colspan="2"><font color="#FF0000"><strong>Invalid User 
Name/Password Please Retype</strong></font></td> 
     </tr> 
     <tr style="height:10px;">
      <td></td>
     </tr> 
     <tr id="login_row"> 
      <td colspan="2">Please enter your Website user name and password 
below:</td> 
     </tr> 
     <tr style="height:10px;">
      <td></td>
     </tr> 
     <tr id="user_row"> 
      <td>User Name:</td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="login_username" size="40" style="width: 
 295px;" value=""></td> 
     </tr> 
     <tr id="password_row"> 
      <td>Password:</td> 
      <td><input type="password" name="login_password" size="40" 
style="width: 295px;"></td> 
     </tr> 
     <tr style="height:10px;">
      <td></td>
     </tr> 
     <tr> 
      <td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td> 
     </tr> 
    </tbody>
   </table> 
  </form> 
  <script type="text/javascript">CsrfMagic.end();</script>  
 </body>
</html>
```

In HTML code there is information "Invalid User Name/Password Please Retype" but i'm sure that provided credential are correct. I have no idea where is problem...

I need that to get image which is available only after login to the website.

Comment: Try to add the `user  agent` string of your browser to the request.

Comment: It's in already.

Comment: Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I see in your HTML code, that there is a hidden input field, which you didn't send to the server.

```
<input type="hidden" name="__csrf_magic" 
value="sid:2cab4af55d51696dff403441da56e8f7777b205d,1501588419">
```

Try to get the value from it using JSoup and provide it as data to the post of your code. Which then means your post could look like this:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://xxx.xx.x.xx/website_after_login/graph_view.php")
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36")
        .data("cookieexists", "false")
        .data("login_username", "login")
        .data("login_password", "password")
        .data("action", "login")
        .data("__csrf_magic", "sid:2cab4af55d51696dff403441da56e8f7777b205d,1501588419")
        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
        .post();
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Unfortunatley I still get the same error - "HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=https://xxx.xx.x.xx/website_after_login/graph_view.php".  I'm not sure if posting 'sid:' is good idea, because it's changing everytime you refresh website. But thank you for this hint. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well, sure it's changing everytime you refresh the website. Are you getting the current `sid` value everytime?

Comment: Yes I'm getting sid value every time.

Comment: That's odd. Only because of curiosity, does it help if you remove the POST value: `.data("cookieexists", "false")`. If that doesn't help as well I'd try to add the input field "submit" `.data("submit", "Login")`

Comment: I tried with different website and it's working. I can't figure it out where i'm making a mistake with this one...

Comment: Well, your code is correct, and should work. Perhaps we are missing another value to send to the server. Maybe try to sniff the POST request with your browser (e.g. Chrome) and have a look what values are posted to the page.

Comment: I done that and it looks like I didn't miss anything: __csrf_magic:sid:68bb95f50c8ff53c5e3bafbb832b8f371a8f7c0c,1502649729
action:login
login_username:login
login_password:password
There's nothing more in Form Data. I will try few more ideas and I will share results with You.